# How do I call an action method on Controller from the outside, with the same behavior by clicking {{action}}

Tags: ember.js

Please look at this code...

```

```
            App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
                model:  return function () {
                    return this.store.find('books');
                }
            });

            App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
                actions: {
                    updateData: function () {
                        console.log("updateData is called!");
                        var books = this.filter(function () {
                            return true;
                        });
                        for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
                            //doSomething…
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

```

I want to call the `updateData` action on BooksController from the outside.

I tried this code.

`App.__container__.lookup("controller:books").send('updateData');`

It works actually. But, in the `updateData` action, the `this` is different from the one in which `updateData` was called by clicking {{action 'updateData'}} on `books` template.

In the case of clicking {{action 'updateData'}}, the `this.filter()` method in `updateData` action will return books models.
But, In the case of calling `App.__container__.lookup("controller:books").send('updateData');`, the `this.filter()` method in `updateData` action will return nothing.

How do I call the `updateData` action on BooksController from the outside, with the same behavior by clicking {{action 'updateData'}}.

I would appreciate knowing about it.

(I'm using Ember.js 1.0.0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use either `bind` or `jQuery.proxy`.  `bind` is provided in JS since version 1.8.5, so it's pretty safe to use unless you need to support very old browsers.  http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/

Either way, you're basically manually scoping the `this` object.

So, if you have this `IndexController`, and you wanted to trigger `raiseAlert` from outside the app.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  testValue : "fooBar!",
  actions : {
    raiseAlert : function(source){
      alert( source + " " + this.get('testValue') );
    }
  }
});
```

With `bind` :

```
function externalAlertBind(){
  var controller = App.__container__.lookup("controller:index");
  var boundSend = controller.send.bind(controller);
  boundSend('raiseAlert','External Bind');
}
```

With `jQuery.proxy`

```
function externalAlertProxy(){
  var controller = App.__container__.lookup("controller:index");
  var proxySend = jQuery.proxy(controller.send,controller);
  proxySend('raiseAlert','External Proxy');
}
```

Interestingly `this` *seems* to be OK without using either `bind` or `proxy` in this JSBin.

```
function externalAlert(){
  var controller = App.__container__.lookup("controller:index");
  controller.send('raiseAlert','External');
}
```

Here's a JSBin showing all of these: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1080/edit

[UPDATE] : Another JSBin that calls `filter` in the action : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1082/edit

[UPDATE 2] : I got things to work by looking up `"controller:booksIndex"` instead of `"controller:books-index"`.

Here's a JSBin : http://jsbin.com/ICaMimo/1/edit

And the way to see it work (since the routes are weird) : http://jsbin.com/ICaMimo/1#/index

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But, those solutions can't resolve my problem.

Those and my approaches can access `this.get('testValue')`, but can not get desired values from `this.filter()` method.

According to my debugging, `this` in which I called `App.__container__.lookup("controller:books").send('updateData');`(or called action by your two ways) and the another one in which I clicked {{action 'updateData'}} are quite different.

I think that the other solutions are needed...

Comment: Hmm... when you call it from inside ember, can you tell exactly what `this` is?  Is it actually the `BooksController`, or is it maybe a view?

Comment: The `this` in which I clicked {{action}} seems to be the BooksController.(Sorry, I could be wrong.)
But something is different. At least, It's properties are different.

Comment: I checked stacktrace as following...  

### by clicking {{action}}  
Ember.ActionHandler.Ember.Mixin.create.send  
(anonymous function)  
Backburner.run  
Ember.run  
Ember.onLoad.ActionHelper.registerAction.ActionHelper.registerdAction.(anonymous function).handler  
(anonymous funciton)  
Ember.handleErrors  
(anonymous fucntion)  
x.event.dispatch           (jQuery)  
x.event.add.v.handle     (jQuery)  
  
### by calling `App.__container__.lookup("controller:books").send('updateData');`  
Ember.ActionHandler.Ember.Mixin.create.send  
(MyLocalScope)

Comment: Meybe, these functions in stack trace seem to affect the instance of controller.

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I don't know how to put linebreak in this comments place. You might have trouble seeing this stack trace.

Comment: Here's a JSBin that uses `this.filter` in the action and things are still working with all 3 methods.  http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1082/edit  Any chance you can put up a JSBin illustrating your problem?

Comment: Here's JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/uKIvAM/7/edit . To run, please access to http://jsbin.com/uKIvAM/7#/index

Comment: I just added an [UPDATE 2] section to my original answer.  The issue is how you're looking up the controller.  It should be `"controller:booksIndex"`.

Comment: Oh, Little did I notice! (since It works by halves.)
Thank you for taking the time to find out the cause. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

### This solved my similar issue

Read more about action boubling here: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling

```
SpeedMind.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        // This makes sure that all calls to the {{action 'goBack'}}
        // in the end is run by the application-controllers implementation
        // using the boubling action system. (controller->route->parentroutes)
        goBack: function() {
            this.controllerFor('application').send('goBack');
        }
    },
};

SpeedMind.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        goBack: function(){
            console.log("This is the real goBack method definition!");
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just have the ember action call your method rather than handling it inside of the action itself.

```
App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
            actions: {
                fireUpdateData: function(){
                    App.BooksController.updateData();
                }
            },

            // This is outside of the action
            updateData: function () {
                    console.log("updateData is called!");
                    var books = this.filter(function () {
                        return true;
                    });
                    for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
                        //doSomething…
                    }
                }
        });
```

Now whenever you want to call updateData(), just use

```
App.BooksController.updateData();
```

Or in the case of a handlebars file

```
{{action "fireUpdateData"}}
```